# Extend root partition size in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition

[image: Gparted analysis of the filesystem]

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

I have been using the above mentioned ubuntu on my laptop. Now, I want to increase the size of root partition as it is almost full. As you can see in the screenshot of gparted tool, there is an unallocated space before the root partition but still it does not allow me to extend the storage space of root partition. Please, someone help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to this from a LiveCD, mounted filesystem cannot be moved (it can be resized, but only "to the right" resizing "to the left" means copying the data and this cannot be done when the device is mounted).

So boot from Ubuntu LiveCD and using GParted *Partition → Resize/Move* move and resize the root partition to the free space.

As with all storage operations, making a backup first is strongly recommended. If something goes wrong during the resize/move operation (for example power failure) you can loose data.

Comment: I would format unallocated partition (sda4) , then **copy** `/dev/sda5` to it, and try to boot on `sda4` this way `sda5`would be it's own backup. note that you will have to edit grud command line on `/` partition.

Comment: I would move it at least 20GB left, just so the copy can be one larger copy rather than many partial copies where the partitions would overlap. That would work but slightly more risky. Any interruption will damage data, so again have good backups. Note your Windows is also full. NTFS wants 30% free to work well. At 10% free a defrag takes forever as it has no working room. Only use Windows tools to resize NTFS partitions.